# type mismatch; found : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.ws.Response] required: play.api.libs.ws.Response

Tags: scala, playframework, future, playframework-2.1

I am trying to make a post request to Pusher api, but I am having trouble returning the right type, I a type mismatch; found : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.ws.Response] required: play.api.libs.ws.Response

```
def trigger(channel:String, event:String, message:String): ws.Response = {
val domain = "api.pusherapp.com"
val url = "/apps/"+appId+"/channels/"+channel+"/events";
val body = message

val params = List( 
  ("auth_key", key),
  ("auth_timestamp", (new Date().getTime()/1000) toInt ),
  ("auth_version", "1.0"),
  ("name", event),
  ("body_md5", md5(body))
).sortWith((a,b) => a._1 < b._1 ).map( o => o._1+"="+URLEncoder.encode(o._2.toString)).mkString("&");

    val signature = sha256(List("POST", url, params).mkString("\n"), secret.get); 
    val signatureEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8");
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
    WS.url("http://"+domain+url+"?"+params+"&auth_signature="+signatureEncoded).post(body
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request you are making with `post` is asynchronous. That call returns immediately, but does not return a `Response` object. Instead, it returns a `Future[Response]` object, which will contain the `Response` object once the http request is completed asynchronously.

If you want to block execution until the request is completed, do:

```
val f = Ws.url(...).post(...)
Await.result(f)
```

See more about futures [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

Comment: In 99% cases you shouldn't await an Async. All the necessary tools to work with future are disponible in the framework.

Comment: thanks Marius and Julien, you are right, this causes a blocking response

Answer (score 3):

Just append a `map`:

```
WS.url("http://"+domain+url+"?"+params+"&auth_signature="+signatureEncoded).post(body).map(_)
```

Comment: thanks for answering, can you explain why this works? I mean, how is the value extracted from the future?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't want to create a blocking app, your method should also return a `Future[ws.Response]`. Let your futures bubble up to the Controller where you return an `AsyncResult` using `Async { ... }` and let Play handle the rest.

Controller

```
def webServiceResult = Action { implicit request =>
  Async {
    // ... your logic
    trigger(channel, event, message).map { response =>
      // Do something with the response, e.g. convert to Json
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I could not find Async {} in the 2.1 api: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/scala/index.html#package

Comment: which library do i import to use Async? How is it different than AsyncResult?
I currently import these two, which might be related:
`import scala.concurrent._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._`

thanks

Comment: It's here https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L669. Just import `play.api.mvc._`

Comment: `AsyncResult` is a subclass of Result, and you create using the `Async {}` wrapper in your Controller action.